# Viewmodel collectasstatewithlifecycle triggered Twice

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have Two composable  Functions where the first function has a list of items, When we click on one of the Items should be added to the List in the Second composable

for this we are using ViewModel

Like this

```
private val _projectDetailAdded = MutableStateFlow<ProjectDetail?>(null)
    val projectDetailAdded = _projectDetailAdded!!.asStateFlow()

    fun updateprojectDetailAdded(newText: ProjectDetail) {
        _projectDetailAdded.value = newText
    }
```

We call the updateprojectDetailAdded function in the first composable when list item is clicked and in the second composable we use

`val projectDetail  = viewModel.projectDetailAdded.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`

However this is triggered Twice and is added in the list of second composable twice

There are multiple items in the first list which we need to add in the second list based on the items selected on click in the first list.

How to trigger the `viewModel.projectDetailAdded.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` only once

Comment: It is hard to help without code snippet of the calling side

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to this? I am facing this issue, and it seems to be because of the collectAsStateWithLifecycle being re-triggered if a mutableStateOf object which was initialized above this collectAsStateWithLifecycle object changes.

Comment: i think there might be something related to launched effect